# iOS 7 landscape error

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I have created an application that pulls down a feed and allows for different articles to be read using different scroll views for different categories. In iOS 6, the user is able to rotate, scroll through the articles through the scroll view and choose their article. Once the user clicks an article a new view controller comes up and displays that article in full through a scroll view. This works fine in whatever orientation.

However, in iOS 7, portrait works fine, but when the user is in landscape, whatever article they choose it always displays the first article in that particular category in the scroll view. Hope that makes sense!

I have a method that pushes the information:

```
ArticleViewController* avc = [[[ArticleViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ArticleViewController" bundle: nil] autorelease];
avc.section = art.section;
avc.articleNumber = [avc.section.articles indexOfObject: art];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: avc animated: YES];
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, I'm using auto layout, but that wouldn't have any effect on the actual content that was being displayed would it?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots to make it a little clearer?

Comment: have you checked for article number (or whatever property that stores the selected index) in the child controller? Is it correct or is it always zero?

Comment: Yes, I've logged out articleNumber on the viewDidLoad and it logs out the correct articleNumber in portrait and landscape, but still displays the wrong article for landscape, but works fine for iOS6

Comment: I've changed my dispatch_after code from `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [scroller scrollToPage: articleNumber animated: NO];
    });`
to:
`dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [scroller scrollToPage: articleNumber animated: NO];
    });`

It nows seems to be working on iOS7, but does load the first page in for a split second because of the dispatch code. Is this really the only way to resolve this and why would it be okay in iOS6 and not iOS7?